# Is there a way to see how many failed builds there are for a job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to see how many failed builds there are for a job in Jenkins.

I've tried various plugins and API calls with no success.

Is there a simple, working way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get count of failures of a particular job:

```
import hudson.model.Result
import groovy.json.*
import hudson.model.Job
def jobName = "<Your job name>"
//def jobName = "Json_test_Pipeline"
def failurecount=0


Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job).each{
         def jobBuilds=it.getBuilds()
          jobBuilds.each { build ->
         
          def currentStatus = build.buildStatusSummary.message
          if ( it.fullName.contains(jobName)) {
          def parameters = build.getAction(ParametersAction)?.parameters
          if (currentStatus.contains("broken")) {
               failurecount = failurecount +1
               println "Build: ${build} | Status: ${currentStatus}"  
            }
         }
        }
    }
    println("Total failure count for job ${jobName} is : ${failurecount}")
```

Output :
[image]

Note : You need to approve Administrator Script approval to have it working.